# Unsupported CPU installed

Tags: hp, central-processing-unit

I got a pc which was in need for an bios upgrade. I downloaded the bios update from the HP site.

After the installation/upgrade from the bios and we restarted te pc we got the error:

> ERROR: Unsupported CPU installed
>   PC will automatically power down in a few second.

The PC is a HP Pavilion a6210
Motherboard: 945gct-hm 
CPU: Intel pentium dual CPU E2140

We can't get into the bios, try a new bios upgrade from USB or anything

The HP support seems to be going nowhere since all they want is money money money
Anyone else had an similar issue? how to restore or anything?

Comment: Is that the stock CPU fitted from the factory?

Comment: Hideously dirty idea of the day: Replace the motherboard bios with coreboot (http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot) perhaps, and then it might work, or permanently brick the motherboard.

Comment: Must be a wrong display from the bios

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised, that motherboard [supports](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01237572);

- Core 2 Duo (Conroe) up to E4300
- Pentium D (Presler) up to 960 (3.6 GHz)
- Pentium 4 (Cedar Mill) up to 661 (3.6 GHz)
- Celeron D (Cedar Mill) up to 365 (3.6 GHz)
- Celeron D (Prescott) up to 355 (3.33GHz)

The E2140 is an [Allendale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28microarchitecture%29) chip, so you're out of luck.

Comment: hmmmm good one, its a stock CPU so im guessing the bios just displaying the wrong CPU. This is most likely the problem

Comment: I'd just call HP.

Comment: Exact name from the website is: Pentium E2140 (C) 1,6 GHz which should be supported by the motherboard

Comment: [link]http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01247767&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=nl&dlc=nl&cc=nl&os=2093&product=3602370&sw_lang=[/link]

Comment: Also, before the bios upgrade, it did work

Comment: Like I say, call HP.

Comment: I agree with Chopper...call.